# Extract the local maxima and minima values from a list using java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a list of values, like so (see the chart):

[image: see the chart]

and I want to extract only the local maxima values and minima (red points) with keeping the same order(min, max, min, max) with java.

i tried to find all max and min and remove some of them based on the percentage between two points, but i feel it doesn't give the right result, i want some ideas about the right algorithm, can anyone help about that?

what i did:

```
    public List<Track> extremumsFinder(double percentage) throws ParseException {
        
        List<Track> extremums = new ArrayList<Track>();
        List<Track> FiltredExtremums = new ArrayList<Track>();
        


    // Checking whether the first point is 
            // local maxima or minima or none 
            if (tracks.get(0).getVolume() > tracks.get(1).getVolume()) {
                tracks.get(0).setType(TrackType.max);
            }
            else { 
                tracks.get(0).setType(TrackType.min);
            }
            
            extremums.add(tracks.get(0));


    
    
    //check the next points 
    for(int i = 1; i < this.size - 1; i++) {

//compare the percentage between current value and previous value

if(this.isTrueExtremum((double) extremums.get(extremums.size() - 1).getVolume(),  (double) tracks.get(i).getVolume(), percentage)) {
    //check if a max or min 
    boolean isMax = this.isMaximum((double) tracks.get(i - 1).getVolume(),  (double) tracks.get(i).getVolume() ,  (double) tracks.get(i + 1).getVolume());
    boolean isMin = this.isMinimum((double) tracks.get(i - 1).getVolume(),  (double) tracks.get(i).getVolume() ,  (double) tracks.get(i + 1).getVolume());

    if(isMax){
        //set the type as max
        tracks.get(i).setType(TrackType.max);
        extremums.add(tracks.get(i));
    } else if(isMin) {
        //set the type as min
        tracks.get(i).setType(TrackType.min);
        extremums.add(tracks.get(i));
    }
}
```

and :

```
[public boolean isTrueExtremum(double previous, double current , double percentage) {
    double diff, diffPercentage;][1]

    //calculate the diff between two points
    diff = Math.abs(current - previous);

    //percentage of the diff beased on the previous point
    diffPercentage = diff / previous;

    if(diffPercentage > percentage) return true;
    else return false;
}

public boolean isMaximum(double previous, double current, double next) {
    // Condition for local maxima
    if ((previous < current) && (current > next)) return true;
    else return false;
}

public boolean isMinimum(double previous, double current, double next) {
    // Condition for local minima
    if ((previous > current) && (current < next)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: (As your data is discrete) any point `Xi` with `Xi-1 < Xi > Xi+1` is a local maxima (and if `Xi-1 > Xi < Xi+1` is a local minima). You need more information to get your chart.

Comment: yes you are right, just i am looking to find only the biggest maximas and minimas, so i can get only 8 points in the result,

Comment: what mean "biggest"? the globals? (then only exists one maxima and one minima)

Comment: kind of, if you take a look on the chart, you will find the red points, that's what i am looking for, i mean the big values only

Comment: _"you will find the red points"_ yes I see but you need a **formal criteria**, that is, if I draw other graph, which red dots will you paint?

Comment: oh yeah, got you, let me explain, i have a list of objects, each object has (value, time), i want to find the objects based on the value.

Comment: you are not understanding that you are not saying how SOME (because you HAVE chosen only some) of the local maxima/minima should be chosen out of ALL there are, why THOSE and not OTHERS?

Comment: You need to find a **formal definition** of how to distinguish the red points you noted from the other "smaller" local minima that exist in your graph (there's plenty of them at lower scales).

Comment: i have no idea about this formal definition, i will appreciate if you give me an example

Comment: @JoachimSauer cannot give you the definition for your selection of the red dots. Why you did not chose the minimum under the max. Instead you went for a more saw shape. Why? that is the definition. Seems to me you are trying to simplify your graph data, get rid of the noise (noise reduction filter). For this there are existing formulas..

Comment: the reason for i want the red dots is, i want to calculate the difference between them and to have the exact result, i need exactly the red dots.